# Add array into array like a Python style

Tags: python, java, arrays, loops, addition

I am trying add an array into another array.

Code:

```
int[] headArray = {16, 3, 2, 13,
               5, 10, 11, 8,
               9, 6, 7, 12,
               4, 15, 14, 1};
int[] miniArray = new int[4]; // helpArray
int[][] array2D = new int[4][4];

int count = 0;
int countIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < headArray.length; i++) {
    miniArray[count] = headArray[i];
    count++;
    if (count == 4) {
        array2D[countIndex] = miniArray;
        count = 0;
        countIndex++;
        // reset miniArray ? how? de-likn array? how?
    }
}
```

When I visualize it, I see 1st loop fill miniArray correctly, then, miniArray will be put into array2D to index 0 correctly, but in next step(s), all indices of array2D are "linked" to last array elements of miniArray ([visualization of work](https://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/java_visualize/#code=public+class+ClassNameHere+%7B%0A+++public+static+void+main(String%5B%5D+args)+%7B%0A++++++int+headArray%5B%5D+%3D+%7B16,+3,+2,+13,%0A+++++++++++++++++++++++5,+10,+11,+8,%0A+++++++++++++++++++++++9,+6,+7,+12,%0A+++++++++++++++++++++++4,+15,+14,+1%7D%3B%0A++++++int%5B%5D+miniArray+%3D+new+int%5B4%5D%3B%0A++++++int%5B%5D%5B%5D+array2D+%3D+new+int%5B4%5D%5B4%5D%3B%0A%0A%09%09int+count+%3D+0%3B%0A%09%09int+countIndex+%3D+0%3B%0A%0A%09%09for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+headArray.length%3B+i%2B%2B)+%7B%0A%09%09%09miniArray%5Bcount%5D+%3D+headArray%5Bi%5D%3B%0A%09%09%09count%2B%2B%3B%0A%09%09%09if+(count+%3D%3D+4)+%7B%0A%09%09%09%09array2D%5BcountIndex%5D+%3D+miniArray%3B%0A%09%09%09%09count+%3D+0%3B%0A%09%09%09%09countIndex%2B%2B%3B%0A++++++++++++//+reset+miniArray+%3F+how%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A+++%7D%0A%7D&mode=display&curInstr=50)) after the loop, my array2D will be like:

```
array2D = {{4, 15, 14, 1},{4, 15, 14, 1},{4, 15, 14, 1},{4, 15, 14, 1}}
```

This is what I expected:

```
array2D = {{16, 3, 2, 13},{5, 10, 11, 8},{9, 6, 7, 12},{4, 15, 14, 1}}
```

Of course, I know correct answer, it can be solved by:

```
int k = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < array2D.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array2D[0].length; j++) {
        array2D[i][j] = headArray[k];
        k++;
    }
}
```

However, it is problem solving like *"I am looking at this problem by "row 0, cell 0, row 1, cell 0" etc..."*, but I am looking at this problem like *"I have 16 stuffs on the table, I will grab 4 of them, put it in to miniBox and after that, put miniBox in to bigBox, then, another 4 stuffs put in to another miniBox and after that, put miniBox in to bigBox, etc etc"* like a Python style:

```py
headArray = [16, 3, 2, 13, 5, 10, 11, 8, 9, 6, 7, 12, 4, 15, 14, 1]

count = 0

for i in range(16): # or range(len(headArray))
    miniArray.append(headArray[i])
    count += 1
    if count == 4:
        array2D.append(miniArray)
        count = 0
        miniArray= []
```

Why does my Python-retranslated code to Java language not work?
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> another 4 stuffs put in to another miniBox

This is what you need to do, but not what you are doing. You are putting the next 4 stuffs into the same miniBox.

To create a new `miniBox`, you need to create after the following line:

```
// reset miniArray ? how? de-likn array? how?
miniArray = new int[4];
```

So the complete loop would be this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < headArray.length; i++) {
        miniArray[count] = headArray[i];
        count++;
        if (count == 4) {
            array2D[countIndex] = miniArray;
            count = 0;
            countIndex++;
            // reset miniArray ? how? de-likn array? how?
            miniArray = new int[4];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new array for each row.

```
int[] headArray = { 16, 3, 2, 13, 5, 10, 11, 8, 9, 6, 7, 12, 4, 15, 14, 1 };
int[][] array2D = new int[4][];

for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < headArray.length; i += 4, ++j)
    array2D[j] = Arrays.copyOfRange(headArray, i, i + 4);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array2D));
```

output:

```
[[16, 3, 2, 13], [5, 10, 11, 8], [9, 6, 7, 12], [4, 15, 14, 1]]
```